# What happens to a skill when an adept learns it as a talent?

Tags: skills, earthdawn-1e

Adepts can learn skills (at increased cost) for abilities that they will eventually be able to learn as talents at higher circles.

E.g. Norman the Windling thief learns the skill 'Missile weapons' at circle one. Many adventures later Norman reaches circle six where he can now learn 'Missile Weapons' as a talent. What happens to Normans existing ranks in his skill?

1. Skill ranks are directly converted to the talent ranks.
2. They are ignored, talents and skills are separate, Norman must learn his talent skill anew.
3. Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW, they are separate things and must be learnt and tracked separatedly.
Talents are (vastly) superior to (mundane) skills, so you will have two different ranks, one for your magical talent and one for your mundane skill, but you will have to pickup which one you want to use.

Skills are the hard way to become good at something, because it takes time and a lot of training to increase, and you have a limit on how good you can be. While talents are the fast and easy route, but you must adventure and put your life at risk to evolve.

So, Norman will have Missile Weapons at rank 1 as a mundane ability, and Missile Weapons at rank 1 as a magical ability.